# Procedural Planets, Heightmaps and textures

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping, fractals, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

I am currently working on an OpenGL procedural planet generator.  I hope to use it for a space RPG, that will not allow players to go down to the surface of a planet so I have ignored anything ROAM related.  At the momement I am drawing a cube with VBOs and mapping onto a sphere as shown [here](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/patchedsphere/patchedsphere.htm).

I am familiar with most fractal heightmap generating techniques and have already implemented my own version of midpoint displacement(not that useful in this case I know).

My question is, what is the best way to procedurally generate the heightmap.  I have looked at [libnoise](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/index.html) which allows me to make tilable heightmaps/textures, but as far as I can see I would need to generate a net like:

[image: this]

Leaving the tiling obvious.

Could anyone advise me on the best route to take?

Any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Henry.

Comment: People can't go down to the surface? Then you don't need heightmaps. If the earth were a basketball, then Mt Everest would be less than one the basketball's bumps. There's not enough variation to make an actual heightmap worth it.

Comment: Well I'm still looking to create planets with visible terrain from space. Even if it seems a little overstated.  In any case I would still like to generate the texture procedurally.

Comment: Something like http://img504.imageshack.us/img504/7848/gc2007sporescreens20070mp2.jpg for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you understand the problem with generating a flat, seamless surface and then trying to map it onto a sphere.

How about using a 3D noise function instead?  A 3D noise function takes 3 coordinates instead of 2 as its input, so imagine a 3D array full of generated numbers (instead of a 2D array).  Thus, once you have a 3D noise function, you can generate a 2D texture, but instead of using 2D coordinates for each pixel, use the 3D coordinates of where that pixel would be on the sphere.  (I hope that convoluted sentence made sense!)

Take a look at halfway-down this page about Perlin noise: https://web.archive.org/web/20120829114554/http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/texture_colour/perlin/

I think it describes exactly what you want with regards to spheres.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen people talking of this on forums but didn't really get a good image of it in my head.  Thanks for your help, and for people who may come by this - http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/docs/classnoise_1_1module_1_1Perlin.html#_details for 3D perlin generator!

Comment: I was about to answer "3d perlin noise" myself but I saw the perlin-noise tag and assumed the author of the original question was familiar with it!

Comment: I know this question is fairly old, but for those that find it in the future also check out simplex noise, it's the updated version of perlin noise and it's less complex.

Comment: This answer is a link-only answer, and the link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out this article from 2004 on how to 'split' up a sphere into manageable parts.

http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2074.asp